# looping through parameters in xsl:template to do something whenever empty

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml-file, which contains some information, which belong to an created diagram. I can extract all the variables I want with xslt. To print them to another file I call different templates and send the variables to it: 
For example some code from my main xslt-file:

```
<xsl:call-template name="HostDefine">
        <xsl:with-param name="variable1" select="@value1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="variable2" select="path/node/@value2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="variable3" select="path/node/@value3"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="variable4" select="@value4"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="variable5" select="@value5"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="variable6">value6</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

In the most templates I have way more than 6 Parameters.

I call the template in another xsl-file like this:

```
<xsl:template name="HostDefine">
    <xsl:param name="Variable1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Variable2"/>
    <xsl:param name="Variable3"/>
    <xsl:param name="Variable4"/>
    <xsl:param name="Variable5"/>
    <xsl:param name="Variable6"/>
</xsl:template>
```

before closing the template now I want to print all variables to the new file in this way:

```
o=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable1"/>
p=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable2"/>
q=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable3"/>
r=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable4"/>
s=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable5"/>
t=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable6"/>
```

Thats my structure. My problem is now, that some of this variables could be empty. Whenever they are empty they should not be printed (and also not the "o=/p=/q=/...". So I need to ask somewhere inside the template if an variable has a value or if it is empty (empty = '').

First I wanted to do it with an "for-each", but I recognized I can only do this with nodes. Than I thought about a kind of for-loop (or in xslt an incremental - call), but then I can't loop through the different parameters. So the only way I see in the moment is to make an if-call before each variable to see if it is empty or not. But with sometimes more than 20 Variables in one template and around 10 templates this will be a really huge thing. Is there any more elegant/better way to do this?

Comment: Define "empty". If you have `<xsl:with-param name="variable1" select="@value1"/>` then the result can be an empty node set (XSLT 1.0) or sequence (XSLT 2.0) if the context element has not `value` attribute or can be a node set or sequence with a single attribute node. In that case you can always check `boolean($variable1)` to check whether the node set or sequence is not empty. However, <xsl:with-param name="variable6">value6</xsl:with-param> is different, the value you set is a result tree fragment or temporary tree.

Comment: If it is empty than there was no "value"-attribute in the node in the xml-File. But it wouldn't be a problem to manuually set it to an empty string or just a blank (' '), whenever there is no "value"-attribute in the node of the xml-file.

My goal is to create an clean and structured code. I can go whichever way seems to be good.

did this answer the question. I m not sure if i got it totally.

Comment: Is that XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Do you always pass all declared parameters or does your statement "In the most templates i have way more than 6 Parameters" indicate that you might have more than 6 parameters declared but sometimes pass less than the declared parameters?

Comment: I use XSLT 1.0. 

I pass the same amout of parameters to one template every time (all that are declared for this template). 
What i wanted to say was, that i have different kind of templates with a different amout of parameters, which I pass to. But for one template i pass everytime the same amout of parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about passing node-sets in XSLT 1.0 then you can declare `<xsl:param name="param-name" select="/.."/>` to ensure the default value is an empty node-set and then you can check

```
<xsl:if test="$param-name">
  ... = <xsl:value-of select="$param-name"/>
</xsl:if>
```

to check that a non empty node-set has been passed.

That approach will work for all your first five sample where you define the passed parameter value using the `select` attribute with an XPath expression selecting nodes.

For the sample with `<xsl:with-param name="variable6">value6</xsl:with-param>` you pass a result tree fragment which is never empty so the `boolean($variable6)` check would not work with that approach.

Comment: So you would do the declaration( `<xsl:param name="param-name" select="/.."/>` inside of the template (`name="HostDefine`) before handing over the variable from the template-call (`<xsl:param name="Variable1"/>`)? And around each of this lines (`o=<xsl:value-of select="$Variable1"/>`) you would place the <xsl:if>.

This was the option i thought it would be really unelegant and big, but if you say this is a good was i will try it like this.

Comment: The declaration of the parameter inside of the template has to happen there, I don't see a way of using parameters without declaring them. Whether you need all those parameters and named templates I don't know, you haven't shown any input samples, any concrete template calls. I certainly wouldn't use parameters for all those attribute selections `select="@value1"`, I would simply select the attributes in the template as needed, as long as there are not different selections necessary for different nodes.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about it quiet long, because my case is quiet confuesing, because of the huge amount of data i need to check (at least it is for me).
I tried your suggestion with declaring  it with a default value. It wasn't working for me with `select="/.."` but with `select="''"` it was possible.
I'm still thinking about how i manage with the parameters (i counted it, in one template it has to be over 45 Parameters).

Thanks for your help.